# Solving a Special Second Order Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

During some research I ran across the following differential equation
$$
f''(x)-(\frac{2px}{1-\frac{x^2}{2q}})f'(x)+\epsilon f(x)=0
$$
where $p$ and $q$ are free  positive parameters and $\epsilon$ is the eigenvalue. The boundary condition on $f(x)$ is that it should not diverge at $x=\pm\sqrt{2q}$. 
The expansion method didn't help since the corresponding recursion equation has three terms which indicates that the solution is not a polynomial. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: in the limit $q\rightarrow \infty$ the differential equation will be similar to the Hermite differential equation and in that case $\epsilon=2pn$

Answer (score 0):

$f''(x)-\dfrac{2px}{1-\dfrac{x^2}{2q}}f'(x)+\epsilon f(x)=0$

$(x^2-2q)f''(x)+4pqxf'(x)+\epsilon(x^2-2q)f(x)=0$

Let $f(x)=e^{nx}g(x)$ ,

Then $f'(x)=e^{nx}g'(x)+ne^{nx}g(x)$

$f''(x)=e^{nx}g''(x)+ne^{nx}g'(x)+ne^{nx}g'(x)+n^2e^{nx}g(x)=e^{nx}g''(x)+2ne^{nx}g'(x)+n^2e^{nx}g(x)$

$\therefore(x^2-2q)(e^{nx}g''(x)+2ne^{nx}g'(x)+n^2e^{nx}g(x))+4pqx(e^{nx}g'(x)+ne^{nx}g(x))+\epsilon(x^2-2q)e^{nx}g(x)=0$

$(x^2-2q)g''(x)+2n(x^2-2q)g'(x)+n^2(x^2-2q)g(x)+4pqxg'(x)+4npqxg(x)+\epsilon(x^2-2q)g(x)=0$

$(x^2-2q)g''(x)+(2nx^2+4pqx-4nq)g'(x)+((n^2+\epsilon)(x^2-2q)+4npqx)g(x)=0$

Choose $n^2+\epsilon=0$ , i.e. $n=\pm i\sqrt\epsilon$ , the ODE becomes

$(x^2-2q)g''(x)+(\pm2i\sqrt\epsilon x^2+4pqx\mp4i\sqrt\epsilon q)g'(x)\pm4i\sqrt\epsilon pqxg(x)=0$

Which relates to [Heun's Confluent Equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/31.12#E1).

Comment: Thanks  doraemonpaul. A point that comes to mind about the way you split $f(x)$ is that $f(x)$ is both real and parity definite so $g(x)$ must be neither real nor parity definite.